# Running raw sql inside Model : Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder, eloquent

I am using Laravel and need to run raw sql query from a Model/Repository class

```
INSERT INTO calendar 
(room_id, date, default_count, default_price) 
VALUES ('1', '2017-01-02', '2', '400004') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
default_count = VALUES(default_count), default_price = VALUES(default_price);
```

ex. When I insert data from UserRepository

```
$this->users->insert(['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]);
```

I need some kind of method to get DB connection and run sql via model

```
//Something like
$this->users->execute($sql);
```

I saw Laravel has `updateOrInsert()` method but I need to run this for multiple data sets at once.

How can I run raw sql query via the model class or repository?

Thanks

**UPDATED - SOLVED**

I went through [Eloquent Model Sourcecode](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/43637b796f1ac0b1a960984231251ff04b438006/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) and found I can get connection from getConnection() method

```
$this->users->getConnection()->statement($sql);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Updated

Comment: You don't **need** that. What you need is to catch an exception and check if it's code contains `23000` which is the code for duplicate key entry. At that point you can simply proceed to update your model. You can create a single method in your model which deals with inserting / catching the exception / checking whether code is 23000 and then updates your model. You can avoid fetching the connection, dealing with transaction and all other nasty things you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through Eloquent Model Sourcecode and found I can get connection from getConnection() method

```
$this->users->getConnection()->statement($sql);
```

don't know statement() is the best way to run this sql. However it worked.

Thanks everyone for help. Also if you have a better solution please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$query = array(['room_id' => 1, 'date' => '2/1/2017', 'default_count' => '2', 'default_price' => '400004'],
['room_id' => 2, 'date' => '2/1/2017', 'default_count' => '3', 'default_price' => '455004']);


 DB::table('calendar')->insart('query');
```

And also you can do like this,
Create obj of your modal and assign values

```
$obj_calendar = new Calendar();
$obj_calendar->room_id = 1;
$obj_calendar->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2017-01-02'));
$obj_calendar->default_count = 2;
$obj_calendar->default_price = 400004;
$obj_calendar->save();
```

---

Using transaction

// begin transaction

```
public function beginTransaction()
{
  DB::beginTransaction();
}
```

// make transaction

```
public function makeTransaction($query)
{
  DB::transaction(function($query) use($query)
  {
    DB::insert($query);
  });
}
```

// commit transaction

```
public function commitTransaction()
{
  return DB::commit();
}
```

In your method

```
public function insert($data)
{
  $this->beginTransaction();

  for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)
  {
    $name =  $data[$i]->first_name, "middle_name" => $data[$i]->middle_name, "last_name" => $data[$i]->last_name;

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(id, first_name, description, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (" . $data[$i]->id . ", " . $name . ", '" . $data[$i]->description . "', '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($data[$i]->created_at)) . "', '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($data[$i]->created_at)) . "'); ";

    $scraper_service->makeTransaction($query);
  }

  //Add last commit 
  $this->commitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I need to run row sql and prefer not to load another class to get connection inside model

Comment: Then use transaction

Comment: I need to run 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/43637b796f1ac0b1a960984231251ff04b438006/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L605-L612

but for multiple data set. Performancewise it's better to run one query instead 10 queries for the same task